# Enforce Microsoft Access database DATETIME format when opening OleDbConnection

Tags: c#, ms-access

I noticed that when I run my application on different computers, the program reads from the database using the DATETIME format of the machine environment, i would like a way for the database to always be read from using a constant format like yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss

Below is the connection string I am using, I'm a total noob at this and only got the connection string from another post on this site.

```
    string conStr = "Provider='Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0';Data Source=" + p_strFileName +
                    ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" + p_strDBPassword +
                    ";Mode=Share Exclusive;Persist Security Info=True;";
    conStr += "Jet OLEDB:System Database=" + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPDATA") +
                    @"\Microsoft\Access\system.mdw";

    OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
```

**EDIT:**

My problem is not displaying, I have an access mdb file with an event table that has a DateTime column which shows the event DateTime. When i read from this database in my program the DateTime column format in the database changes to that of the machine environment (uses the Region settings that have been set on the operating system)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no date fields, but date and time are not read in a format but as a value.

For display, a default format is used if you don't specify a format. You can use ToString:

```
dateString = dateValue.ToString("yyyy'/'MM/'/'dd hh':'mm':'ss");
```

Comment: My problem is not displaying, i have an access mdb file with an event table that has a DateTime column which shows the event DateTime. When i read from this database in my program the DateTime column format in the database changes to that of the machine environment (uses the Region settings that have been set on the operating system)

Comment: Yes, that is default behaviour by design. If you wish another format, you will have to specify it. Again, date and time is values of no particular format.

Comment: is there perhaps a way to change the systems's region format from within my application?

Comment: Not really, and if there where, you shouldn't; your application should not alter basic settings of the user's workstation. If you application requires a specific format, apply this to the textboxes and other controls where you display the date/time values.